# Google analytics, Track user answers in quiz app (Android)

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have a Quiz app with four alternatives for each question. It would be interesting to get a report of the user answers, i.e question id, and number of click for each alternative answers.

|Q.id|Alt.1|Alt.2|Alt.3|Alt.4|

|1   |  5  |  15 | 0   |  40 |

|2   |  2  |   5 | 10  |  40 |

|3   |  10 |  1  | 34  |  10 |

How, if it is possible, can I generate a report with the questions and count the different answers?

**Edit:**
I tried to use an "Event", but the report was not what I was looking for. My code is simple:

```
// Build and send an Event.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .setCategory(String.valueOf(q.getQuestionId()))
    .setAction(answer)
    .setLabel(String.valueOf(isCorrect))
    .build());
```

I was hoping for one record in the report with *category* (question id), *action* (the user answer to the question, A,B,C or D) and *label* (correct or not (0/1)), but these three was divided into three different reports.... (E.g. counting the total number of A,B,C and D's)...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show code. And what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to google it. So the first question is, is it possible? What should I use? Event tracking?